# Can't POST after extending User model fields in Django REST

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am able to extend User model fields and I can see API browser with these fields and inputs, but when I try to POST a new user I got this error:

```
'signup' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

or if I change in **serializers.py**

```
User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

to

```
SignUp.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I got

```
'username' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(source='signup.city')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'city')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

## models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUp(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this through the [`related_name` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in your model and then you can reference it on the serializer.

```
class SignUp(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, related_name='signup') # <---
```

I don't think you can flatten nested fields into the parent model's serializer.

You can do a nested field:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(source='signup')
```

If you access it via the JSON path, you'll get an object like:

```
{
    url: "localhost:8000/users/1",
    username: "foo",
    email: "foo@example.com",
    signup: {
        city: "Seattle"
    }
 }
```

Comment: I created AbstractUser to extend custom User model on one table. Now everything is working and I don't have nested fields.